# Using QChart in visual studio

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qt5.8

I am trying to use the Qt QChart to plot a line graph. I am using visual Studio 2013 with Qt 5.8. I created a simple QApplication. When I paste  QLineSeries *series it says QLineSeries is undefined. How can I fix this?

```
#include "QtGuiApplication2.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtGuiApplication2 w;

    QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What's your toolchain? Visual studio with Qt VS Tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to link against QT5Charts under:

```
general properties
- Linker
  - Input
   - add the path: e.g. C:\Libraries\Qt\Qt5.7.0\msvc\lib\Qt5Chartsd.lib
```

I suppose, you don't forget to add the namespace?

```
using namespace QtCharts;
```

if you work with cmake, just add this to your cmake file:

```
find_package(Qt5Charts)
target_link_libraries(${targetName} Qt5::Charts)
```

Comment: @soeren- I Tried that, I added it under additional Dependencies

Comment: and the namespace?

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I had also "undefined" all `#include` for QtCharts library. After a prolonged series of google searches, the following actions helped me (considering Visual Studio 2019 with Qt 5.15.2):

1. Check if you have macros `$(Qt_INCLUDEPATH_)` in (Project -> [Project] Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories) and macros `$(Qt_LIBS_)` in (Project -> [Project] Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies). They should already have all the paths for the `lib` directories. You can check it by pressing near the field (Arrow down -> Edit... -> Macros>> -> [Insert the macros name]). If you have the paths in these macros then you don't need to add them again and go directly to point 3. If not, go to point 2.
2. Add a common path in (Project -> [Project] Properties -> General -> Additional Library Directories) as `C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\lib` (it can be a little different for you). With this precision, only the relative path can be mentioned in (Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies) i.e. `Qt5Chartsd.lib`. In (Project -> [Project] Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories) write the absolute path as `C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCharts` (again, can be different).
3. With Qt VS Tools, there are new fields in (Project -> [Project] Properties ->...). You need (Qt Project Settings -> Qt Modules). As in Qt Creator, there's a need to add a new module `charts`. With (Arrow Down -> Select Modules...) near the field, you can even see all the modules which it's possible to activate. For me, I finally had `core;gui;widgets;charts`.
4. **The solution worked for me without that point but just in case** - add all the required dynamic libraries `.dll` in the same directory with your `.exe` project file. `.dll` libraries load at run time so they might help in certain cases.